# How to extend object properties with other in Scala?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala, how to extends one properties value from other object. Like in angular, `angular.copy(obj1, obj2);`

If I have two objects, `obj1`, `obj2`, both having the same property names. `obj2`'s value would be overridden to `obj1`.

How to achieve this in Scala?

Comment: Scala doesn't have this feature. But maybe you can find some library which can do it using reflection.

Comment: First of all Scala strongly discourages mutable objects. So, such functionality to mutate objects will not be part of Scala standard lib or any other popular library. If you are using Scala, you should not be thinking of such mutations but if you really require it, you can look into an Optics based solution.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh `scala.collection.mutable` contains lots of mutable objects. While a pure functional style is preferred, Scala is pragmatic enough to accept that mutable data is often the best way to implement some algorithms.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh The mutability is not the interesting part of the question, it can be a copy-type method, just like all case classes have built-in. The tricky part is not having to explicitly name all the fields.

Comment: Using only what Scala offers out of the box, you need to explicitly name each field. As a beginner, I suggest you stick with that. The solutions using code generation and such are quite complex unless you already have a good grasp of the basics.

Comment: @Thilo those are mutable collections, a bit different from objects with mutable attribute variable. Anyways like I specified in my comment, if required then you can choose to have mutables. That is the freedom provided by Scala and even those `val`'s can be mutated by reflection.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Again, the mutability is not the interesting part of the question. The interesting part is how to avoid having to explicitly name each field (and whether that is worth the trade-offs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike JavaScript, Scala does not allow you to add new properties to existing objects. Objects are created with a specific *type* and that type defines the properties on the object. If your objects are implemented as a `case class` then it is easy to make a copy of an object:

```
val obj = obj1.copy()
```

You can also update some of the fields of `obj1` during the copy and leave others untouched:

```
val obj = obj1.copy(count=obj2.count)
```

This will create a new object with all the same values as `obj1` except for the field `count` which will take the value from `obj2`.

It has been noted in the comments that in Scala you will typically create new objects from old ones, rather than modifying existing objects. This may seem cumbersome at first but it make it much easier to understand the behaviour of more complex code because you know that objects won't change under your feet.

Answer (score 0):

## Note on `object` in Scala vs JS

Note that `object` in Scala as a completely different concept from the usage in Javascript.
Scala deliberately is not using Prototype base inheritance.
So in short that this is not possible is a feature not a mssing capability of the language.

see https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/singleton-objects.html

## Solution : Use a Map to simulate protoype base inheritance/composition

You can use a Map to achieve a similar behaviour:

```
scala> val sayHello = () => "Hello"
sayHello: () => String = <function0>

scala> val obj1 = Map("sayHello" -> sayHello , "id" -> 99)
obj1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(sayHello -> <function0>, id -> 99)

scala> val obj2 = Map("id" -> 1)
obj2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(id -> 1)

scala> obj1 ++ obj2
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Any] = Map(sayHello -> <function0>, id -> 1)
```

Comment: This completely defeats the purpose of using a typesafe language though. So unless this is really a dictionary-type thing (i.e. dynamic field names and ideally uniform field value types) I'd swallow the boilerplate of proper case classes.